# PreUpdate listener triggered during empty update

Tags: java, jpa, sql-update, jpql

I have an entity with the last modified attribute:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date lastModified;

@PreUpdate
@PrePersist
protected void onUpdate() {
    lastModified = new Date();
}
```

and a named jpql update query, which sets some attributes for old entities:

```
update entity e set ... where e.lastModified < :threshold
```

The onUpdate() method is however called even for entities, which has not been modified, that is event if:

```
entityManager.createQuery("...").executeUpdate();
```

returns zero as the number of updated entities.

Can I update only the old entities without touching the recent ones? The threshold parameter is not known in the updated entity, so I cannot move the update into onUpdate() method. Can native query help me in this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you replace the `@PreUpdate/@PrePersist` mechanism with a `@Version` on the lastModified field ? This way all updated entity will have the field set (and only updated ones).

It should make the job as you expect if I understood well your case.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry guys, it was my fault in my junit tests. The onUpdate() is not called at all during bulk update (even for modified entities). I was confused by some other updates being delayed until the first select.

After reading more documentation about @Version, as suggested by Gab, I've found, that bulk updates (using the jpql) bypasses the entity manager and discovered, that the same applies for PreUpdate listeners. The problem wasn't therefore in my update code, but in my tests.

Comment: could you please provide the associated link ?

Comment: I've found that @Version bypasses the entity manager in http://indo-java-podcast.googlecode.com/files/devday4.pdf